# Websocket connection attempt fails, returns "Connection: Upgrade, close."

Tags: java, tomcat, websocket

I'm building a Java websocket server using Tomcat.  On my dev build, it works perfectly.  However when I deploy it to production, the server is automatically appending "close" to the connection response header, immediately closing the socket (which never seems to connect to the server in the first place).

Here's some context for the production environment:

- Tomcat 7, Java 8 on RHEL
- Communications are encrypted by SSL, websocket uses wss
- The server is behind an institutional firewall (but I expect that the encryption should make this a non-issue)

My local dev environment is not an exact clone (as it's used for multiple projects). It's running Tomcat 8, but I believe Tomcat 7 should feature comparable websocket support.

Here's the request/response (as captured by Chrome dev tools) when the websocket is sent to the production server:

General:

```
Request URL: wss://example.com/WSServer
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 101 Switching Protocols
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols
Date: Thu, 10 May 2018 17:04:39 GMT
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Upgrade: websocket
Connection: upgrade, close
Sec-WebSocket-Accept: JFNyciPc/Cza8PFaXWVct6f21qw=
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate;client_max_window_bits=15
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
```

Request:

```
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: Upgrade
Cookie: *redacted*
Host: example.com
Origin: https://example.com
Pragma: no-cache
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits
Sec-WebSocket-Key: OvMcwMxIYqBLrx9ijlFK/w==
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
Upgrade: websocket
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.139 Safari/537.36`
```

As far as I can tell, the most revealing part of this is `Connection: upgrade, close`, which explains the client-side behavior below.

Here's a snippet of the client-side Javascript:

```
var socket = new WebSocket((window.location.protocol==="http:"?"ws:":"wss:") + "//" + window.location.host + "/WSServer");

socket.onopen = function wsOpen() {
    socket.send("Hello!"));
}

socket.onclose = function wsClose(reason) {
    log(JSON.stringify(reason)); //debug
}
```

socket.onopen gets called first. Executed normally, this doesn't produce any console message, but if I delay its execution with a breakpoint I get an error message: "Websocket is already in CLOSED or CLOSING state."

socket.onclose gets called immediately after.  The reason code is 1006 with no explanation.

I've also put some debug logging in the ServerEndpointConfig.Configurator.modifyHandshake method, but it never reaches that point, nor does it reach the @OnOpen-annotated method.

Any idea what's causing the connection to fail?  Again, the server and client code works in dev, so I'm confident that it's not a code issue.  Is it a Tomcat configuration issue (as far as I can tell, there's nothing unusual about the way it's setup).  Is there something obvious I'm missing?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: It seems likely that there is a proxy involved in the production environment and it is not configured to allow webSocket connections.

Comment: @jfriend00 Thanks!  However I thought that a proxy or firewall couldn't identify encrypted websocket transmissions nor the initiating HTTPS request (it would just look like any other TCP traffic). Is that not the case? Also, if it matters, according to http://websocketstest.com/ I can establish a websocket connection on port 443 from within the network.

Comment: In a hosted environment, the proxy is often the actual endpoint for the HTTPS.

Comment: Practical use of WebSocket requires that any reverse-proxies handling the HTTP (and WS) protocol understand how to handle that protocol. A firewall isn't usually doing anything other than filtering packets based upon what is in the TCP/IP or UDP/IP headers. If you actually have a reverse-proxy there, it might be terminating HTTPS. If it's terminating HTTPS then it must also understand how to handle WebSocket.

Comment: Thank you both.  I'll have to take this up with the higher-ups.  I greatly appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP/1.1 enables keep-alive connections by default.
A request such as:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
Connection: close
```

tells the server to disable keep-alive on the connection (the opposite of the HTTP/1.1 default)

`Upgrade` is a hop-by-hop header, just like `Connection`, and `Upgrade` is only valid if listed in `Connection`, e.g. `Connection: Upgrade`

When a client makes an HTTP/1.1 request containing `Upgrade`, the server receiving the request is not required to upgrade, and can instead simply respond with an HTTP/1.1 response.

`Connection: upgrade, close` **requests** that the server upgrade to (one of) the protocol(s) in the `Upgrade` header, or else to respond with HTTP/1.1 and close the connection.  If the server upgrades the protocol, then the server uses the new protocol, and the `close` token in `Connection` is ignored, as the server is now using the upgraded protocol in the `Upgrade` response header immediately after the `HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols` response.